# SIGBART error trying to connect to a TCP server on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, tcp

I'm making use of the [CocoaAsyncSocket Library](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) to try and set up a simple TCP connection from my iOS device to a server somewhere and right now I'm trying to simply trying to check my set up and that I'm connecting to a remote ip address.

After downloading the library I've opened the following project:

> GCD->Xcode->ConnectTest->Mobile

I've opened this one as I believe this is simplest example and showcases what I need it to do.
I've ran the program in the editor without touching the code and it works as intended. But when I bring the code over to my program I get the follow Log errors:

```
     -[BTLECentralViewController window]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17e2c460
     *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[BTLECentralViewController window]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17e2c460'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (0x314a0e8b 0x3b79a6c7 0x314a47b7 0x314a2f55 0x313f1e98 0xc5e89 0x33c2ab3b 0x33c2a8f9 0x33db75a3 0x33cd51df 0x33cd4fe9 0x33cd4f7d 0x33c26533 0x338adf43 0x338a9767 0x338a95f9 0x338a900d 0x338a8e1f 0x338a2b4d 0x3146bf71 0x314698ff 0x31469c4b 0x313d4541 0x313d4323 0x3610b2eb 0x33c8b1e5 0xc4bb9 0x3bc93ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

In the same that I've taken the code from they have set up the connection within their AppDelegate class. I've taken this and put in within the view controller that I want this to activate on.

So right now my viewcontroller.h looks like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class GCDAsyncSocket;
@class BTLECentralViewController;

@interface BTLECentralViewController : UIViewController <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    GCDAsyncSocket *async_socket;
}

@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet BTLECentralViewController *view_controller;

@end
```

And the accompanying .m file is as follows. I will only post the code methods for which I've added the new code to. I won't waste your time by putting in the entire class.

```
#import "GCDAsyncSocket.h"

#if USE_SECURE_CONNECTION
#define HOST @"www.paypal.com"
#define PORT 443
#else
#define HOST @"google.com";
#define PORT 80
#endif

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Start up the CBCentralManager
    _centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];



    dispatch_queue_t mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();

    async_socket = [[GCDAsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:mainQueue];

#if USE_SECURE_CONNECTION
    {
        NSString *host = HOST;
        uint16_t port = PORT;

        DDLogInfo(@"Connecting to \"%@\" on port %hu...", host, port);
        self.viewController.label.text = @"Connecting...";

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![asyncSocket connectToHost:@"www.paypal.com" onPort:port error:&error])
        {
            DDLogError(@"Error connecting: %@", error);
            self.viewController.label.text = @"Oops";
        }
    }
#else
    {
        NSString *host = HOST;
        uint16_t port = PORT;

        //  DDLogInfo(@"Connecting to \"%@\" on port %hu...", host, port);
        _estimote_3_label.text = @"Connecting...";

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![async_socket connectToHost:host onPort:port error:&error])
        {
            //      DDLogError(@"Error connecting: %@", error);
            _estimote_3_label.text = @"Oops";
        }

        // You can also specify an optional connect timeout.

        //  NSError *error = nil;
        //  if (![asyncSocket connectToHost:host onPort:80 withTimeout:5.0 error:&error])
        //  {
        //      DDLogError(@"Error connecting: %@", error);
        //  }

    }
#endif


    // Normal iOS stuff...

    self.window.rootViewController = self.view_controller;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];  
}
```

As I said, my hope for this was to come through with a "Connected" string appearing in my debug log. But when I run it I get the debug log error I've pasted at the top and a SIGBART error in my main class which looks like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Can anyone with more experience using the library please help me out and tell me what it is I've done wrong and why I'm getting these errors?

Please note, in the editor the sample project works fine and running it on my iPhone 5 works fine. it's just when I bring the relevant code over to my project that I get these issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BTLECentralViewController and UIViewController doesn't have window property you are trying to use:

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.view_controller;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

That should be placed in AppDelegate (UIResponder) class I believe.